# where clause on a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

So here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm creating a generic class that allocates the type specified by the generic parameter in one of two ways, determined by which overloaded constructor is used.

Here is the example:

```
class MyClass<T>
    where T : class
{
    public delegate T Allocator();
    public MyClass()
    {
        obj = new T();
    }

    public MyClass( Allocator alloc )
    {
        obj = alloc();
    }

    T obj;
}
```

This class requires that type T is a reftype in all cases. For the default constructor, we want to instantiate T via its default constructor. I'd like to put a `where T : new()` on my default constructor, like this:

```
public MyClass()
    where T : new()
{
    obj = new T();
}
```

However, this is not valid C#. Basically I only want to add the constraint on type T to have a default constructor only when the default constructor of MyClass() is used.

In the second constructor for MyClass, we let the user determine how to allocate for T with their own allocation method, so obviously it makes sense for MyClass to not enforce T be default constructible in all cases.

I have a feeling that I'll need to use reflection in the default constructor for this, but I hope not.

I know this can be done because the `Lazy<T>` class in .NET 4.0 does not require T to be default constructible at the class level, yet it has constructors similar to those in my example. I'd like to know how `Lazy<T>` does it at least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only include constraints in the declaration where you're *introducing* a generic type parameter.

However, you could introduce a generic *method* on a non-generic *type*:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass<T> Create<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        return new MyClass<T>(() => new T());
    }
}

public class MyClass<T> where T : class
{
    T obj;

    public MyClass(Allocator allocator)
    {
        obj = allocator();
    }
}
```

(I'd personally just use `Func<T>` instead of declaring a separate delegate type btw.)

Then you can use:

```
MyClass<Foo> foo = MyClass.Create<Foo>(); // Enforces the constraint
```

Comment: Changing my answer to this one... I did some reading on `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` and indeed it doesn't do the check for default construction at compile time (which I prefer). I went with the generic factory class instead.

Comment: How can you define MyClass twice without using the 'partial' keyword? I'm not familiar with this syntax.

Comment: @Robert Dailey: I haven't declared `MyClass` twice - I've declared `MyClass` (non-generic) and `MyClass<T>` (generic with one type parameter). They're separate types, just as `Nullable` and `Nullable<T>` are separate types.

Answer (score 7):

> Basically I only want to add the constraint on type T to have a default constructor only when the default constructor of MyClass() is used.

It is not possible to enforce this with a constraint on `T`. You either have it be the case that `where T : new()` is specified in the definition of `MyClass<T>` or you do without such a constraint at all.

> I have a feeling that I'll need to use reflection in the default constructor for this, but I hope not.

You can't enforce the constraint, but you can say

```
obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

which will invoke the default constructor for `T`.

> I know this can be done because the Lazy class in .NET 4.0 does not require T to be default constructible at the class level, yet it has constructors similar to those in my example. I'd like to know how Lazy does it at least.

`Lazy<T>` requires you specify a delegate that returns instances `T`. Basically, it requires you to specify a `Func<T>`.

Comment: You *can* enforce the constraint - just not in the constructor. Introducing it in a generic method elsewhere works fine.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The constraint the OP is requiring can not be enforced on the type parameter `T` that is defined by the generic class `MyClass<T>`.

Comment: Not on the type itself, no... but you can create a simple generic method on a non-generic type, and use that instead of a public parameterless constructor - see my answer. The point - as I understand it - is to provide a simple but compile-time-safe way of creating an instance of `MyClass` using the parameterless constructor for `T`. My answer does that.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `Activator`

```
class MyClass<T> where T : class
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: also: `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`

Comment: That leaves the checking to execution time, which isn't ideal IMO.

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` only checks if it is default constructible at runtime?

Answer (score -2):

Well, you need to either have the constraint or not. It turns out that Lazy uses Activator to create an instance. <strike>Here is how `Lazy<T>` works</strike> removed code in case of copyright issues.

Comment: I am not sure the license of the .NET BCL code allows for posting it on the internet...

Comment: Noted. Lock me up and throw away the key!

Comment: What kind of a response is that?

Comment: +1 Daniel... The Microsoft Reference License allows you to view it if you have signed the agreement... Which most on here have not.